# Verifying the Google Cloud Function in Google Web center

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3

Everything went well, except of Adding the domain. Just I cannot add Google Cloud Function url and verify it.

APIs & Services > Domain verification.

Any ideas how to do this? Is it possible to add TXT record to https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/ ?

Comment: Please put all of the information you need in the question.

Comment: Got the same issue. When following this tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3. They say like verify domain but how to do it is not included in the tutorial.

Comment: We might need more information to address this. What is the Error message you see when trying to follow the steps in the doc? I read it and you don't need to verify it but to add it into the authorized domains. Maybe I'm missing something, so I would like to have more details about this.